# TSQL check constraint related to existing rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable] 
(
    ID1 [int] NOT NULL,
    ID2 [int] NOT NULL,
    StartDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
    EndDate smalldatetime NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID1 ASC, ID2 ASC, StartDate ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to ensure that the `StartDate` to `EndDate` period for each ID1 and ID2 is unique, and that there is no overlap.

How to create a check constraint like this:

```
(
    ID1 <> existingRow.ID1
    or ID2 <> existingRow.ID2
)
or (
    ID1 = existingRow.ID1
    and ID2 = existingRow.ID2
    and (
        StartDate >= isnull(existingRow.EndDate, Startdate + 1)
        or isnull(EndDate, existingRow.StartDate + 1) <= existingRow.StartDate
    )
)
```

...or a constraint with a condition like this:

```
IF ID1 = existingRow.ID1 and ID2 = existingRow.ID2
CHECK (
    StartDate >= isnull(existingRow.EndDate, Startdate + 1)
    or isnull(EndDate, existingRow.StartDate + 1) <= existingRow.StartDate
)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you'll have to use trigger for such a validation

Comment: I can't quite follow your pseudo-code, but are you essentially looking for a [temporal table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015(v=sql.130).aspx)? That is, at any given moment in time, there's exactly one "valid" row for a given `ID1`, `ID2` combination?

Comment: If so, you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6035413/15498) useful

Comment: I will try ughai's idea of a 'before insert/update trigger'. thx... ;)

Comment: The answer I linked to may seem to be more work than "just" using a trigger but has the advantage that the actual correctness has been modelled in the constraints on the table. The triggers in that answer just hide some of the moving parts.

Comment: You can do it with a check constraint that calls a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_check_unique_value 
(
    @ID1 INT,
    @ID2 INT,
    @StartDate SMALLDATETIME,
    @EndDate SMALLDATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT

    SET @Result = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM   dbo.myTable existingRow
                   WHERE  (   @ID1 <> existingRow.ID1
                             or @ID2 <> existingRow.ID2
                            )
                            or (
                                @ID1 = existingRow.ID1
                                and @ID2 = existingRow.ID2
                                and (
                                     @StartDate >= isnull(existingRow.EndDate, @Startdate + 1)
                                     or isnull(@EndDate, existingRow.StartDate + 1) <= existingRow.StartDate
                                    )
                               ))

    RETURN @Result
END
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD CONSTRAINT CK_No_Overlap
    CHECK ( dbo.fn_check_unique_value(ID1, ID2, StartDate, EndDate) <= 1
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two tables: One that stores just the ID1 and ID2 columns, and one that copies the table you have now. You can then add a series of triggers to the first table that, after inserting, updating or deleting, will insert or update the second table. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableOne
(
    ID1 [int] NOT NULL,
    ID2 [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID1 ASC, ID2 ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
create table TableTwo(
    ID1 int not null,
    ID2 int not null,
    StartDate smalldatetime not null default(getdate()),
    EndDate smalldatetime not null
)
GO
create trigger tTableOneAfterInsert on TableOne after insert
as begin
    update TableTwo 
        set EndDate = getdate()
    from TableTwo 
        join inserted on TableTwo.ID1 = inserted.ID1 and TableTwo.ID2 = inserted.ID2
    where TableTwo.EndDate is NULL

    insert into TableTwo(ID1, ID2)
    select ID1, ID2 from inserted
end
GO
create trigger tTableOneAfterUpdate on TableOne after update
as begin
    update TableTwo 
        set EndDate = getdate()
    from TableTwo 
        join inserted on TableTwo.ID1 = inserted.ID1 and TableTwo.ID2 = inserted.ID2
    where TableTwo.EndDate is NULL

    insert into TableTwo(ID1, ID2)
    select ID1, ID2 from inserted
end
GO
create trigger tTableOneAfterDelete on TableOne after delete
as begin
    update TableTwo 
        set EndDate = getdate()
    from TableTwo 
        join deleted on TableTwo.ID1 = deleted.ID1 and TableTwo.ID2 = deleted.ID2
    where TableTwo.EndDate is NULL
end
```